# How to remove the "new" prefix from several attributes of the element in the request to the SOAP service?

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws

I have a wsdl. Using wsdl2java i have created java classes and add realization.  After that i created project in SOAP UI i receive the next xml for request:
[image]

The problem is that i have hardcoded client which will use one of operation of this web sevice and the client will not work if `new` prefix will exist. 
How to remove `new` prefix from `login` and `password` attributes of AuthData element?

**UPDATE**

When i call web-service like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sin="http://my.comp/2010/webservice/Service" xmlns:new="http://www.webservice.namespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sin:AuthData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <new:login>121212</new:login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <new:password>12121</new:password>
      </sin:AuthData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

it works fine. But when i delete prefic `new` i receive thw mistake:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"login"). Expected elements are &lt;{http://new.webservice.namespace}login>,&lt;{http://new.webservice.namespace}password></faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As i said the problem is than cl;ient can't send request with `new` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect day: ask a question and answer himself. Some time later.
In my case i need to correct `package-info.java` class and change `elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)` to `UNQUALIFIED` in it. These problems could have been avoided if during the build classes are generate automatically by **jaxb2-maven-plugin** (whuch in my case i can not use due to project structure).