# How to remove the “ser” prefix from SOAP request attributes in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm trying to remove the 'ser' attribute from the following SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://localhost/server">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:eRoamingChargeDetailRecord>
         <SessionID>?</SessionID>
      </ser:eRoamingChargeDetailRecord>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="localhost/blah">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <eRoamingChargeDetailRecord xmlns:ns2="localhost/blah" xmlns="localhost/blah">
         <SessionID>?</SessionID>
      </eRoamingChargeDetailRecord>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, when I remove this prefix manually, the server returns the following error:

```
Procedure 'eRoamingChargeDetailRecord' not present
```

The SOAP server is set up in PHP like so:

```
if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
            ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
            $soapAutoDiscover = new \Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover(new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence());
            $soapAutoDiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
            $soapAutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
            $soapAutoDiscover->setClass('\\App\\Helpers\\Soap\\SoapFunctions');
            $soapAutoDiscover->setUri('http://localhost/server');
            $soapAutoDiscover->handle();
        } else {
            $soap = new \Zend\Soap\Server('http://localhost/server?wsdl', array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_1));
            $soap->setObject(new \Zend\Soap\Server\DocumentLiteralWrapper(new \App\Helpers\Soap\SoapFunctions()));
            $soap->handle();
        }
}
```

And the function is:

```
/**
 * This method takes ...
 *
 * @param string $SessionID
 * @return string
 */
public function eRoamingChargeDetailRecord($SessionID) {
    return "hello2 {$SessionID}";
}
```

How can I remove this ser prefix?

[I've found similar questions on SO, but these are related to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826581/how-to-remove-the-new-prefix-from-several-attributes-of-the-element-in-the-req)